# Azure Functions App C# .NET 2.0 - Share Code

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function app that will have about 5 functions.  I'm using C# .Net Core 2.0.  I'm doing all development in Visual Studio and will publish app to Azure.  I've seen examples of using a .csx file to share code using the portal and .Net 4.61.  I want to know how to do it in .Net Core 2.0 doing development in Visual Studio.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by “share code”? When you deploy precompiled DLLs from VS, you do not see the source code in the Portal as when you would write the code in the Azure portal. This is independent whether it’s .NET core or .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with it I think I figured it out.

Function App Structure

```
    MyFunctionApp
    Func1 Folder
    ---Func1.cs
    Func2 Folder
    ---Func2.cs
    Func3 Folder
    ---Func3.cs
    Func4 Folder
    ---Func4.cs
    Shared Folder
    ---Utils.cs
```

Func1/Func1.cs

```
    //Func1/Func1.cs
    using static MyNameSpace.Shared.Utils;
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    namespace MyNameSpace
    {
        public static class Func1
        {
            [FunctionName("Func1")]
            public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
                int x = MyAdd(5, 7);
                log.LogInformation($"Result: {x}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Shared/Utils.cs

```
   //Shared/Utils.cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    namespace MyNameSpace.Shared
    {
        static class Utils
        {
            public static int MyAdd(int num1, int num2)
            {
                return num1 + num2;
            }
        }
    }
```